# issue in spliting an value with comma in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to split an value from xml using XSLT1.0 i have a XML like

```
<employees>
    <examples>
       <example id="1,2,3">
       </example>
    </examples>

   <emp id="1">
     <name>john</name>
   </emp>
   <emp id="2">
     <name>raj</name>
   </emp>
   <emp id="3">
     <name>sat</name>
   </emp>

</employees>
```

I need to extract the id from the example tag and split it and get the value from the `emp` tag say the output should be

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>john</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>raj</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>sat</name>
    </employee>

</employees>
```

Comment: The example id contains "4", but this is not shown in the output. Is this a type?

Comment: @TimC Updated.Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think than rather than trying to split the @id attribute on the **example** element, which is a bit messy in XSLT1-0, you could instead try and match the **emp** elements whose @id appears in the @id of the attribute

```
 <xsl:variable name="ids" select="concat(',', examples/example/@id, ',')"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="emp[contains($ids, concat(',', @id, ','))]"/>
```

Note the use of commas to ensure an @id of 1 is not picked up by an example @id of 11

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="employees">
      <employees>
         <xsl:variable name="ids" select="concat(',', examples/example/@id, ',')"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="emp[contains($ids, concat(',', @id, ','))]"/>
      </employees>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="emp">
      <employee>
         <id>
            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
         </id>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </employee>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<employees>
   <employee>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>john</name>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>raj</name>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <id>3</id>
      <name>sat</name>
   </employee>
</employees>
```